# $⊢ ∀x∀y(f(x) \neq f(y) → x \neq y)$

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers, natural-deduction

Solve the exercice in Fitch notation using natural deduction for first order logic and not using completeness.

Should I start by removing the quantifiers or by making a subproof where I start with $f(x) \neq f(y)$ and try to get $x \neq y$?

Comment: What do yo know about "="? In particular, which rules of inference talk about it?

Comment: You must have an [equality axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) like : $x=y \to (f(x)=f(y))$.

Comment: I have rules for $=$ as you can see on this [image](https://i.gyazo.com/da1fdce5dcfdaa063a5f7d87009d1157.png). The left one is the introduction of $=$ and the right one is the elimination.

Comment: You have to use $=$-elim.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA if I use $=$ elimination I should get $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ separately right?

Comment: You need a "careful" written version of $=$-elim : usually, the symbol $\varphi[t/x]$ denotes the expression got from $\varphi$ by simultaneously replacing **each** free occurrence of $x$ with $t$. This form does not work well for function symbols. What we need is : "from $x=y$ and $\varphi$, infer $\varphi'$" where $\varphi'$ is obtained from $\varphi$ by replacing $x$ in **zero or more** (but not necessarily all) places by $t$. It is enough to assume $\varphi$ atomic, and then prove the "general" case by induction.

Comment: Alternatively, like in Dirk van Dalen, [Logic and Structure](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA94) (5th ed - 2013), page 94, assume as primitive the rule : "from $x=y$, infer $f(x)=f(y)$".

Comment: Should it be something like this? [solution](https://i.gyazo.com/a2f9036c0ac51e280c04dc809eeee65a.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how exactly your rule for universal introduction (or universal generalization) is defined, or how you do a proof by contradiction in the system that you use, but the proof below will give you the general idea:

[image]

The crucial steps are of course 5 and 6.

For 5, notice that the $= Intro$ rule says that you can introduce an equality between any two of the same *terms* $t$, so you can use it to get $a = a$, but we can also use it (as I did here) to get $f(a) = f(a)$. If you have never seen this before, that may look a bit weird, but it makes perfect sense: since $f(a)$ is a term, it denotes some object, and whatever that object is, it is of course the same as itself. So: $f(a) = f(a)$!

For 6, we used $= Elim$ to replace the second $a$ in $f(a) = f(a)$ with a $b$, which we can do, since $a = b$. Again, this may look weird, since we are not replacing all of the $a$'s with $b$'s, but the rule says that you can replace *any* of the $a$ with $b$'s; it does not say that you have to replace *all* of them. So again, this is a perfectly good use of the rule.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understood every step of the proof but is there any way I could not use negation rules to get to the solution of the problem? I need to get $⊢ ∀x∀y(f(x) \neq f(y) → x \neq y)$ at the end of the deduction and not $⊢ ∀x∀y(¬f(x) = f(y) → ¬x = y)$.

Comment: Something like this should be also correct, right? [solution](https://i.gyazo.com/a2f9036c0ac51e280c04dc809eeee65a.png)

Comment: $x \not = y$ is exactly the same as $\neg x = y$!  It is just a different and more intuitive way to write $\neg x = y$. Indeed, notice that in your proof you derive $x \not = y$ through a $\neg Intro$!

Comment: Basically I followed your answer but I used $≠$ instead of negations. Can you confirm if my solution is right?

Comment: Yes, it's correct!